# Select and Delete from Multiple Layers at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, select, delete

I have imported a CAD drawing into QGIS as a GPK. It has imported everything that was in CAD. Now I want to delete features that I don't need. See below:

[image]

I know how to turn each layer on and then select the features in that layer and then delete them, but as there are many layers it will take a lot of time to delete it one by one. Is there a way to select all of this together and delete it?

Comment: would it work to copy the features you *do* need into a new shapefile instead?

Comment: No, because I would have to select that one by one as well and then would have to paste it one by one into each layer

Comment: Sounds like a 12 of one, 1/2 dozen of the other problem...

Comment: With PyQGIS, you can make a loop that goes through all your layers, select items to delete on each layer and then delete

Comment: If its vector data you can use the `merge vector layers` tool to combine the multiple layers into one (or three layers at most, if they're not all the same geometry type). Then you can select and delete the features you don't want all in one step (or select and copy the features you do want).